# QGIS Profile tool does not plot graph

Tags: terrain, profile

I tried to use the Terrain Profile tool, but it wont display any graph, no plot, just grey. It calculates the values in the table, but it seems some plugin is missing or not working but I have no idea what it could be.

Can anyone help me finding out the problem?

I am using Max OSX Lion

I installed matplotlib 1.3.0-3. several times

[image: System]

Comment: Is there any specific info written in the log panel (View > Panel > Log Messages)? Also, your QGIS version is a bit old (2.0.1). You might want to try with a newer version.

Comment: No, it says "profile tool loaded" and QGIS is ready. You are right, I want to try a newer version, but the newest (2.14) does not work on OS X 10.7. I tried to download a newer version than my current, but couldn't find it anywhere..